# How to Check old IOS app Deployment Target 7.0 on New Version with 9.0

Tags: ios7, ios9, xcode8, ad-hoc-distribution

If I build my app deployment target set to 7.0 will it be compatible with iOS versions up to 10 for adhoc testing.

Comment: If you set "Base SDK" to `Latest iOS (OS10)`, yes.

Comment: @shallowThought The Base SDK is irrelevant. An app with a given deployment target can run on any device with that version of iOS or later.

Comment: @maddy: true. I shot too fast. Sorry Faisal.